# Configure typescript to stop failing compilation if import is not used

Tags: typescript

I've google but I can't quite find out how to tell the Typescript compiler to stop failing compilation when I import a dependency but don't use it.

Commenting out code for comparison is something I frequently do and having to delete/comment out the corresponding imports has become a bit of a pain, especially when most times I'll add the code back a few seconds later.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I'm using create-react-app-typescript.

Comment: Looks like you need to add `"noUnusedLocals": false` in the tsconfig.json - see [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Answer (score 2):

Set compiler option in 'tsconfig.json'.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now support for [@ts-ignore](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18457). This appears to be merged into the master branch, but not sure which TS release its available in, so in theory, this should work:

```
// @ts-ignore: unused
/// <reference path="../scripts/typedefinitions/royalslider.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> I frequently do and having to delete/comment out the corresponding imports has become a bit of a pain, especially when most times I'll add the code back a few seconds later.

## Live with the options and errors

Its okay to have TypeScript errors as you still get output JavaScript (with default options). The errors exist just to make sure you don't commit and cause confusion for others.

## Alternatively

Don't recommend this but here you go:

### Silence errors

Use `//@ts-ignore` to silence the error.

### Change the options

You can change the `tsconfig` options i.e. `"noUnusedLocals": false,` as well as `"noUnusedLocals": false,`.